# Will it be possible to remove the avatar of another person through the slash command?

Tags: discord.py

how is the slash command to get avatar of other members? Help gives me an error I know it is not the same code as normal commands such as client or bot

Answer (score -1):

you can access sender avatar url using `ctx.message.author.avatar_url`

```py
@client.command()
async def avatar(ctx):
    print("sender avatar url: " + ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
```

Comment: my doubt is with the forward slash commands example: /av (member) optional and that the image of the user that has been mentioned appears

Comment: anyway thanks for the help